# How to format html table to show unique months and item id and sum the cost? (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I have been stuck for days on this 'little' problem.
I have one array which contains specific data:

```
$data = array(
0 => array('id' => 8, 'month' => 1, 'cost' => 12500),
1 => array('id' => 8, 'month' => 2, 'cost' => 14200),
2 => array('id' => 9, 'month' => 1, 'cost' => 23000),
3 => array('id' => 9, 'month' => 2, 'cost' => 18000),
);
```

And this is the html table results i need to get:

```
Id     Jan      Feb      Mar     Apr        May
 8    12,500  14,200  10,200   10,300     11,000
 9    23,000  18,000  21,320   10,642     14,636
```

How i can sort array to display this data in html table on view.ctp ?
I have tried using **foreach** loops but i really don't know how to put unique months and unique id like it is displayed above. I'm using CakePHP 2.x technology.

I appreciate every help. Thank you

Comment: Could there be numerous costs to same user/month?

Comment: I've answered how to convert the array into your requested tabular output. However, the "_and sum the cost_" in your headline is neither explained nor seen in the sample output. If that is actually a requirement, please update your post with further details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over your array and group into a new array based on the ID. Assign `month=cost` key-value pairs, using IDs as the grouping keys of your multidimensional array.

```
$by_id = [];

foreach($data as $x) {
    $by_id[$x['id']][$x['month']] = $x['cost'];
    // e.g. $by_id[8][2] = 14200;
}
```

This will turn your sample data into the following array:

```
array(2) {
    [8] · array(2) {
        [1] · int(12500)
        [2] · int(14200)
    }
    [9] · array(2) {
        [1] · int(23000)
        [2] · int(18000)
    }
}
```

That should be much easier to turn into a HTML table. For example like this:

```
$html = [];
$html[] = '<table>';
$html[] = '<tr><th>ID</th><th>Jan</th><th>Feb</th></tr>';

foreach($by_id as $id => $months) {
    $html[] = '<tr>';
    $html[] = "<td>{$id}</td>";

    foreach($months as $month => $cost) {
        $html[] = "<td>{$cost}</td>";
    }
    
    $html[] = '</tr>';
}

$html[] = '</table>';

echo implode("\n", $html);
```

I trust the code is clear enough without elaborate comments. Add months to the table header as necessary. Use e.g. `number_format` for `$cost` to format your monies. *Be aware that the sample code above doesn't account for possible missing months for a given ID*, it assumes symmetric data. Add checks and remedies if necessary. See demo at https://3v4l.org/7CFRf.

Comment: This is the closest answer i have been looking for. Thank you. The only problem is that i need to write unique months from array , not in raw format like you wrote.  If you could provide me any hint about that it would solve the problem.

Comment: @K1m4 can you please clarify "write unique months" vs. "raw format", preferably with an example. (Output from the code here matches the target output as seen in your question.)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a 2D array to display that kind of table.

Then the $data array might be like this:

```
$data = array(
    0 => array('id' => 8, 'costData' => array(
        0 => array('month' => 1, 'cost' => 12500),
        1 => array('monnt' => 2, 'cost' => 14200)
    ),
    1 => array('id' => 9, 'costData' => array(
        0 => array('month' => 1, 'cost' => 23000),
        1 => array('month' => 2, 'cost' => 18000)
    )
);
```

To revert the $data array like this, the code below will be needed.

```
<?php
$newData = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++)
{
    $newItem = array('id' => $data[$i]['id'], 'costData' => array(
        'month' => $data[$i]['month'],
        'cost' => $data[$i]['cost']
    ));
    for($j = $i + 1; $j < count($data); $j++)
    {
        if($data[$j]['id'] == $data[$i]['id']) {
            $newItem['costData'][] = array('month' => $data[$j]['month'], 'cost' => $data[$j]['cost']);
            array_splice($data, $j, 1);
            $j--;
        }
    }
    $newData[] = $newItem;
}
```

Using new data Array, you can make your html page like this.

```
$html = '';
for($i = 0; $i < count($newData); $i++)
{
    $html .= '<tr>';
    $html .= '<td>'.($newData[$i]['id']).'</td>';
    for($j = 0; $j < count($newData[$i]['costData']); $j++) {
        $html .= '<td>'.($newData[$i]['costData'][$j]).'</td>';
        // you can do some operations if there are missing months to leave blank td tags..
    }
    // fill the missing months to fill the td tags.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of the array_column() and array_sum() functions:

$data = array(

array('id' => 8, 'month' => 1, 'cost' => 12500),

array('id' => 8, 'month' => 2, 'cost' => 14200),

array('id' => 9, 'month' => 1, 'cost' => 23000),

array('id' => 9, 'month' => 2, 'cost' => 18000),

);

$result = array();

foreach ($data as $row) {

$result[$row['id']][$row['month']] = $row['cost'];

}

// Sum the costs for each month

$months = array_column($data, 'month');

$result = array_map(function($v) use ($months) {

return array_sum(array_intersect_key($v, array_flip($months)));

}, $result);

print_r($result);

This will output:

Array

(

[8] => Array

(

[1] => 12500

[2] => 14200

)

[9] => Array

(

[1] => 23000

[2] => 18000

)

)